# Why is my code crashing python when the length of the string is not 3 but works when it is 3?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
#carPark

from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("OCR's car park program")

frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

def program():
    loop = True

    while loop:
        if len(plateNumber.get()) == 3:
            welcome.config(text = "Valid plate number.")
            loop = False
        elif len(plateNumber.get()) != 3:
            welcome.config(text = "Invalid plate number.")
            askPlate()

def askPlate():
    global plateNumber
    plateNumber = Entry(frame)
    plateNumber.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    plateNumberLabel = Label(frame, text = "Enter the last 3 digits of your car's plate number: ")
    plateNumberLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    checker = Button(root, text = "Click me when you're done.", command = program)
    checker.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

    try:
        plateNumber.delete(END, 0)
    except:
        pass

welcome = Label(root, text = "Welcome to OCR's car park program.")
welcome.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
price = "2"
pricePay = Button(root, text = "Click me to accept the £" + price + " ticket fee.", command = askPlate)
pricePay.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Whenever I enter an input that is equal to the length of 3 it works but when it isn't equal to 3 it just crashes. I don't know why this is happening and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: I presume your `while` loop is supposed to be inside the `program` defintion?

Comment: In the actual code it is yeah, Andrew

Comment: Then, fix your indentation. Hint: paste in the code, select it and press the `{}` button.

Comment: Your `elif` clause never sets `loop` to `False` so it will just continue infinitely. I would suggest that, in the context of what you have so far, you place a `global loop` in your `askPlate` function and then set `loop` to `False` at the end. Although consider reconfiguring your code to avoid using `global`

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"?  Do you get an exception message?  If so, show it.